# SAS date conversions

Tags: sas

I have below macro variable with yymmn6. format.

```
%let a=201501;
```

I want to have a new macro variable b based on macro a with '2015-01-01'(teradata format). So that i can call  macro b in where condition

I tried below codes.

```
%let b=%sysfunc(put(&a.,year4.)||'-'||put(&a,month2.)||'-01'||"'");
%put &b.
```

Result:OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 ERROR: Expected close parenthesis after macro function invocation not found.
 61
 62
 63          %let b=%sysfunc(put(&a.,year4.)||'-'||put(&a,month2.)||'-01'||"'");
 64          %put &b.
 65

```
   %let b=%sysfunc(putn(&a.,yymmn6.),yymmdd10.);
```

Result:

%let b=%sysfunc(putn(&a.,yymmn6.),yymmdd10.);
 64               %put &b.
 65
 66         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 251203  OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK

```
%let a=201501;
data _null_;
date=input("&a.",yymmn6.);
call symput('date1' , "'"||put(date,year4.)||'- 
'||put(date,month02.)||'-01'||"'");
run;
%put &date1.;
```

for above data *null* the result iam getting is

68         %put &date1.;
 '2015- 1-01'

So all iam trying to do is convert 201501 to 2015-01-01 and looking to be solved using %let macro not in call symput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong.  The important one is that 201501 is not a SAS date.  SAS stores dates as the number of days since Jan 1, 1960.  To you, 201501 represents Jan 1 2015.  To SAS, 201501 represents September 10, 2511.

In the macro language, you can call the INPUTN function to convert 201501 to the SAS date for Jan 1 2015, then call the PUTN function to convert that to YYYY-MM-DD format you want.

```
%let a=201501 ;
%let a_SASdate=%sysfunc(inputn(&a,yymmn6.)) ;
%let b=%sysfunc(putn(&a_SASdate,yymmdd10.)) ;
%put &=a &=a_SASdate &=b ;

A=201501 A_SASDATE=20089 B=2015-01-01
```

You can do it all in one statement, if you don't mind lots of parentheses:

```
%let b=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(inputn(&a,yymmn6.))
                    ,yymmdd10.
                )) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your month representation *yyyymm* to *yyyy-mm-01* using

- `%sysfunc` to not require a data step and invoke the functions `inputn` and `putn`
- `inputn` to convert the month representation to a sas date value
- `putn` to convert the sas date value to *yyyy-mm-dd* representation

Example

```
%let month = 201501;
%let fom_date = %sysfunc(inputn(&month,yymmn6.));
%let fom_ymd = %sysfunc(putn(&fom_date,yymmdd10.));

%put &=month;
%put &=fom_date;
%put &=fom_ymd;
```

As a macro that single quotes the emitted representation so as to be a Teradata date literal.

```
%macro ymn_to_tddl (month);
%* emit teradata date literal corresponding to month;
%* month - month representation as yyyymm;
%str(%')%sysfunc(putn(
    %sysfunc(inputn(&month,yymmn6.))
   ,yymmdd10.
   ))%str(%')
%mend;

%put %ymn_to_tddl (201501);
```

---- log ----

```
'2015-01-01'
```