# How to get the current month and year in YYYYMM format in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to use Call Symput and define a variable called "Current_Month" which will give me the year and month in YYYYMM format. For instance, for the current month Feb'2023, the output should come as 202302. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAS date conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188065/sas-date-conversions)

Answer (score 2):

Using straight macro logic:

- `today()` function to generate today's date
- `sysfunc()` to call the `today()` function within the macro. Note the second parameter to `sysfunc()` can be a format to format the output.

```
%let currentMonth = %sysfunc(today(), yymmn6.);

%put &currentMonth.;
```

log:

```
 68         
 69         %let currentMonth = %sysfunc(today(), yymmn6.);
 70         
 71         %put &currentMonth.;
 202302
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call symputx()` in a data step to generate a macro variable. (you would only want to use the older `call symput()` routine if you need the macro variable to contain trailing or leading spaces).

You can use the YYMMN6. format to display a date value as a digit string where the digits represent the four digit year and two digit month of the date.

```
data _null_;
   call symputx('current_month',put(today(),yymmn6.));
run;
```